# Adding labels with many data points close to one another

Tags: r, plot

I want to add labels next to data points. I know this has been answered several times on this site and the text function works great but is there any other trick I can use with R base functions to make labels visible when there are many overlapping data points? Below is an example of data plotted with number labels but most of them cannot be distinguished.

Scatterplot:

[image]

Comment: ggplot has a `geom_label_repel` feature if you'd be willing to switch to that. Or only label a select few, like outliers or something?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have:

```
library(gapminder); library(ggplot2)
ggplot(gapminder[gapminder$year == 2007,],
        aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp, label = country)) +
  geom_text(check_overlap = T)
```

[image]
A few common techniques around overplotting text:

1) if you don't mind missing some, use check_overlap:

```
ggplot(gapminder[gapminder$year == 2007,],
        aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp, label = country)) +
  geom_text(check_overlap = T)
```

[image]

2) `ggrepel`'s `geom_text_repel` will iteratively nudge the text to reduce/eliminate overlaps. In this case the number of points is so large I had to shrink the font to make it work at all.

```
ggplot(gapminder[gapminder$year == 2007,],
    aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp, label = country)) +
  ggrepel::geom_text_repel(size = 2, box.padding = 0.01)
```

[image]

3) If you're plotting along a line, you might sample points regularly:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y0 = runif(100))
df$y = cumsum(df$y0)
ggplot(df[ c(rep(FALSE,4), TRUE), ], # sample every 5th row. otherwise:  ggplot(df, 
       aes(x, y, label = y)) + 
  geom_text()
```

With and without sampling:

[image]

[image]